# Quill.js add a custom javascript function into the editor

Tags: javascript, html, quill

I am using Quill.js to have users create custom user designed pages off the main web page. I have a custom slider that I have written in javascript that will take images and rotate through them. I have the toolbar in quill setup to be able to click on the toolbar to setup the slider in a modal window.

When the user clicks to close the modal slider setup window, I'm trying to insert an edit button in the html editor where the cursor sits so the user can edit the information that was just entered or possible delete the button by removing all the information in the slider modal window.

I have written custom blots, followed all the examples I could find and nothing worked. I did get a custom html tag to show, but not a button. When I requested the html from quill when I setup the custom html tag in the editor, all I get is "

" from quill.root.innerHTML none of the custom tag or the information in it even though I see it correctly in the editor.

I would like a button in the editor to make it easy to edit the slider data, as there could be more than one. I am not going to limit the number of sliders. It is up to the user to ruin their own page.

I will not be rendering the slider in the edit html window, just trying to display a button to click on. I do give the user a preview button on the modal window to view the slider if they so choose.

I also would like to store the setup information of the slider in a data tag in json format in the button and change that html button to a  tag along with the json data when rendering the html in the browser window.

Can this be done in Quill.js?

Comment: Hello, any news?

Answer (score 1):

I did this by using the import blots embed. I don't register as a button but clicking on the blot I do get a link to the embedded data and trigger the edit of the carousel data on that click.

```
var Quill;
const BlockEmbed = Quill.import("blots/block/embed");
const Link = Quill.import('formats/link');


class Carousel extends BlockEmbed {
    static create(value) {
        var self = this;
        const node = super.create(value);
        node.dataset.carousel = JSON.stringify(value);
        value.file.frames.forEach(frame => {
            const frameDiv = document.createElement("div");
            frameDiv.innerText = frame.title;
            frameDiv.className += "previewDiv";
            node.appendChild(frameDiv);
        });
        node.onclick = function () {
            if (Carousel.onClick) {
                Carousel.onClick(self, node);
            }
        };
        return node;
    }

    static value(domNode) {
        return JSON.parse(domNode.dataset.carousel);
    }

    static onClick: any;

    static blotName = "carousel";
    static className = "ql-carousel";
    static tagName = "DIV";
}

Quill.register("formats/carousel", Carousel);
```

I then include this as a script on the page where quill is editing the HTML

```
<script src="~/js/quilljs-carousel.js"></script>
```

And then this is the custom javascript to handle the events of the blot displayed in a custom modal dialog in a hidden div tag

```
<script>
    function CarouselClicked(blot, node) {
        editCarousel(JSON.parse(node.dataset.carousel), node);
    }

    var Carousel = Quill.import("formats/carousel");
    Carousel.onClick = CarouselClicked;

    function carouselToolbarClickHandler() {
        createCarousel();
    }

    var Toolbar = Quill.import("modules/toolbar");
    Toolbar.DEFAULTS.handlers.carousel = carouselToolbarClickHandler;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var div = $("#editor-container");
        var Image = Quill.import('formats/image');
        Image.className = "img-fluid";
        Quill.register(Image, true);
        var quill = new Quill(div.get(0),
            {
                modules: {
                    syntax: true,
                    toolbar: '#toolbar-container'
                },
                theme: 'snow'
            });
        div.data('quill', quill);

        // Only show the toolbar when quill is ready to go
        $('#toolbar-container').css('display', 'block');
        div.css('display', 'block');
        $('#editor-loading').css('display', 'none');
        // Override the quill Image handler and create our own.
        quill.getModule("toolbar").addHandler("image", imageHandler);
    });

    function createCarousel() {
        $("#carouselModalForm").removeClass("was-validated").get(0).reset();
        $("#carouselModalList").empty();
        $("#carouselModal")
            .data("state", "unsaved")
            .one("hidden.bs.modal",
                function() {
                    var data = getCarouselData();
                    var carouselData = {};
                    carouselData['file'] = data;
                    carouselData['speed'] = $('#time').val();
                    carouselData['height'] = $('#height').val();
                    carouselData['width'] = $('#width').val();
                    var quill = $("#editor-container").data().quill;
                    var range = quill.getSelection(true);
                    if (range != null) {
                        quill.insertEmbed(
                            range.index,
                            "carousel",
                            carouselData,
                            Quill.sources.USER
                        );
                        quill.setSelection(range.index + 2, Quill.sources.USER);
                    }
                })
            .modal("show");
        $('#title').get(0).outerText = "Create Carousel";
    }

    function editCarousel(value, node) {
        $("#carouselModalForm").get(0).reset();
        var elem = $("#carouselModalList").empty();
        $.each(value.file.frames,
            function(i, data) {
                $("<option>").appendTo(elem).text(data.title).data("frame", data);
            });
        $('#time').val(value.speed);
        $('#height').val(value.height);
        $('#width').val(value.width);

        var modal = $("#carouselModal");

        modal.find("form").removeClass("was-validated");
        modal
            .data("state", "unsaved")
            .one("hidden.bs.modal",
                function() {
                    if ($("#carouselModal").data("state") !== "saved")
                        return;
                    var data = getCarouselData();
                    var carouselData = {};
                    carouselData['file'] = data;
                    carouselData['speed'] = $('#time').val();
                    carouselData['height'] = $('#height').val();
                    carouselData['width'] = $('#width').val();
                    var carousel = Quill.find(node, true);
                    carousel.replaceWith("carousel", carouselData);
                })
            .modal("show");
        $('#title').get(0).outerText = "Edit Carousel";
    }

    function getCarouselData() {
        var options = $("#carouselModalList").find("option");
        var frames = $.map(options,
            function(domNode) {
                return $(domNode).data("frame");
            });

        return {
            frames : frames
        };
    }

    function getCarouselFrameFormData() {
        // Get data from frame
        function objectifyForm(formArray) { //serialize data function
            var returnArray = {};
            for (var i = 0; i < formArray.length; i++) {
                returnArray[formArray[i]['name']] = formArray[i]['value'];
            }
            return returnArray;
        }

        return objectifyForm($("#carouselFrameModalForm").serializeArray());
    }

    $("#carouselModalNewFrame").click(function() {
        $("#carouselFrameModalForm").removeClass("was-validated").get(0).reset();
        $("#backgroundPreview").attr("src", "");
        $("#mainPreview").attr("src", "");
        $("#carouselFrameModal")
            .data("state", "unsaved")
            .one("hidden.bs.modal",
                function() {
                    if ($("#carouselFrameModal").data("state") == "saved") {
                        var data = getCarouselFrameFormData();
                        $("<option>").appendTo($("#carouselModalList")).text(data.title).data("frame", data);
                    }
                })
            .modal("show");
        // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to

    });

    $("#carouselModalEditFrame").click(function () {
        var form = $("#carouselFrameModalForm");
        form.removeClass("was-validated").get(0).reset();
        var selected = $("#carouselModalList option:selected");
        var frame = selected.data("frame");
        $.each(Object.keys(frame),
            function (i, e) {
                $("input[name=" + e + "]", form).val(frame[e]);
            });
        $("#backgroundPreview").attr("src", frame.backgroundImg);
        $("#mainPreview").attr("src", frame.mainImg);
        $("#carouselFrameModal")
            .data("state", "unsaved")
            .one("hidden.bs.modal",
                function() {
                    if ($("#carouselFrameModal").data("state") == "saved") {
                        var data = getCarouselFrameFormData();
                        selected.text(data.title).data("frame", data);
                    }
                })
            .modal("show");
    });

    $("#carouselModalRemoveFrame").click(function () {
        $("#confirm-delete").modal("show");
    });

    $("#carouselFrameModalForm").find("input:file").change(function() {
        var elem = $(this);
        var target = elem.data("target");
        var preview = elem.data("preview");
        FiletoBase64(this, preview, target);
    });

    $("#carouselModalList").change(function() {
        var selected = $("option:selected", this);
        $("#carouselModalEditFrame,#carouselModalRemoveFrame").prop("disabled", !selected.length);
    });
    $("#carouselModalSave").click(function() {
        // Validate frameset
        var form = $("#carouselModalForm").get(0);
        var select = $("#carouselModalList");
        if (select.find("option").length == 0) {
            select.get(0).setCustomValidity("Need at least one frame");
        } else {
            select.get(0).setCustomValidity("");
        }
        if (form.checkValidity()) {
            $("#carouselModal").data("state", "saved");
            $("#carouselModal").modal("hide");
        }
        else {
            $("#carouselModalForm").addClass("was-validated");
        }

    });
    $("#carouselFrameModalSave").click(function() {
        // Validate frame
        if ($("#carouselFrameModalForm").get(0).checkValidity()) {
            $("#carouselFrameModal").data("state", "saved");
            $("#carouselFrameModal").modal("hide");
        }
        else {
            $("#carouselFrameModalForm").addClass("was-validated");
        }
    });
    $('#confirm-delete-delete').click(function () {

        $("#carouselModalList option:selected").remove();
        $("#confirm-delete").modal("hide");


    });

    // #region Image FileExplorer Handler
    function insertImageToEditor(url) {
        var div = $("#editor-container");
        var quill = div.data('quill');
        var range = quill.getSelection();
        quill.insertEmbed(range.index, 'image', url);
    }

    function CarouselMainimageHandler() {
        $("#CarouselMainimageSelectFileExplorer").fileExplorer({
            directoryListUrl: '@Url.Action("DirectoryList", "FileTree")',
            fileListUrl: '@Url.Action("FileList", "FileTree")'
        });
        $("#CarouselMainimageSelectModal").modal("show");
    }

    $("#CarouselMainimageSelectModal").on("hide.bs.modal",
        function() {
            $("#CarouselMainimageSelectFileExplorer").fileExplorer("destroy");
        });
    $("#CarouselMainimageSelectSelectButton").click(function() {
        var id = $("#CarouselMainimageSelectFileExplorer").fileExplorer("getSelectedFileId");
        if (id == null) {
            alert("Please select a file");
            return;
        }
        var imageName = $("#CarouselMainimageSelectFileExplorer").fileExplorer("getSelectedFileName");
        var imageLink = "@Url.Action("Render", "FileTree")?id=" + id;
        $("#mainImageName").val(imageName);
        $("#mainImageLink").val(imageLink);
        $("#mainImage").attr("src",imageLink);
        $("#mainImage").show();
        $("#CarouselMainimageSelectModal").modal("hide");
    });


    function CarouselBackgroundimageHandler() {
        $("#CarouselBackgroundimageSelectFileExplorer").fileExplorer({
            directoryListUrl: '@Url.Action("DirectoryList", "FileTree")',
            fileListUrl: '@Url.Action("FileList", "FileTree")'
        });
        $("#CarouselBackgroundimageSelectModal").modal("show");
    }

    $("#CarouselBackgroundimageSelectModal").on("hide.bs.modal",
        function() {
            $("#CarouselBackgroundimageSelectFileExplorer").fileExplorer("destroy");
        });
    $("#CarouselBackgroundimageSelectSelectButton").click(function() {
        var id = $("#CarouselBackgroundimageSelectFileExplorer").fileExplorer("getSelectedFileId");
        if (id == null) {
            alert("Please select a file");
            return;
        }
        var imageName = $("#CarouselBackgroundimageSelectFileExplorer").fileExplorer("getSelectedFileName");
        var imageLink = "@Url.Action("Render", "FileTree")?id=" + id;
        $("#backgroundImageName").val(imageName);
        $("#backgroundImageLink").val(imageLink);
        $("#backgroundImage").attr("src",imageLink);
        $("#backgroundImage").show();
        $("#CarouselBackgroundimageSelectModal").modal("hide");
    });


    function imageHandler() {
        $("#imageSelectFileExplorer").fileExplorer({
            directoryListUrl: '@Url.Action("DirectoryList", "FileTree")',
            fileListUrl: '@Url.Action("FileList", "FileTree")'
        });
        $("#imageSelectModal").modal("show");
    }

    $("#imageSelectModal").on("hide.bs.modal",
        function() {
            $("#imageSelectFileExplorer").fileExplorer("destroy");
        });
    $("#imageSelectSelectButton").click(function() {
        var id = $("#imageSelectFileExplorer").fileExplorer("getSelectedFileId");
        if (id == null) {
            alert("Please select a file");
            return;
        }
        insertImageToEditor("@Url.Action("Render", "FileTree")?id=" + id);
        $("#imageSelectModal").modal("hide");
    });
    // #endregion

    function Save() {
        var div = $("#editor-container");
        var quill = div.data('quill');

        $('#alertSave').show();
        $.post({
            url: '@Url.Action("Save")',
            data: { BodyHtml: quill.root.innerHTML, locationId: @(Model.LocationId?.ToString() ?? "null") },
            headers: {
                '@Xsrf.HeaderName': '@Xsrf.RequestToken'
            }
        }).done(function() {
            $('#alertSave').hide();
            $('#alertSuccess').show();
            setTimeout(function() { $('#alertSuccess').hide(); }, 5000);
        }).fail(function(jqXhr, error) {
            var alert = $('#alertFailure');
            var text = $("#alertFailureText");
            text.text(error.ErrorMessage);
            alert.show();
        });
    }

    function FiletoBase64(input, imgName, Base64TextName) {
        var preview = document.getElementById(imgName);
        var file = input.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.addEventListener("load",
            function() {
                preview.src = reader.result;
                document.getElementById(Base64TextName).value = reader.result;
            },
            false);
        if (file) {
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    }
</script>
```